# MS Excel - VBA Automation Error.

Tags: vba, excel, automation, runtime-error

I have a suite of MS-Excel scorecard calculators that I send to 200 odd clients. In all client environments save 1 the calculators work 100%. However one client is experiencing the following problem.

Periodically the spreadsheet gets a Microsoft Visual Basic Run-Time Error. The exact message is:

```
Microsoft Visual Basic  
Run-time error '-2147417848(80010108)':  
Automation error.
```

As I mentioned, this happens only at one customer site. Everywhere else the spreadsheet runs 100%.

Can anyone shed some light as to why this happens at one site out of 200 odd.

Comment: This is impossible to diagnose from the information provided. You will need to isolate the location of the error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to provide some diagnosis.

1. Do a search of user's system for any *.exd files. They may be in a hidden folder.
2. Delete any *.exd file you find. They are temporary files and will be rebuilt by Excel.

Try to run the file again.  Sorry I can't provide more detailed help, but this is a start based on the information provided.